# APT: install specific version of a package

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

I need to install specific package version, but it does not work with APT:

```
root@myhost:~# apt-get install my-lib-java=2016.03.30-79
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  my-lib-java
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 93 not upgraded.
```

Older version is already installed:

```
root@myhost:~# dpkg -l | grep my-lib-java
ii  my-lib-java                  2016.02.25-3-g5aa415e-75            amd64        no description given
```

But my explicitly specified version does exist:

```
root@myhost:~# apt-cache madison my-lib-java
my-lib-java | 2016.04.19-86 | https://my.re.po/dl/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
my-lib-java | 2016.03.30-79 | https://my.re.po/dl/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
my-lib-java | 2016.02.25-73 | https://my.re.po/dl/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
```

How may I install 2016.03.30-79?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, the problem with APT was that my-lib-java depended on my-lib so the solution is

```
apt-get install my-lib-java=2016.03.30-79 my-lib=2016.03.30-79
```

Then it goes through.